# Setting up an inclusion-exclusion question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

What is the number of one-to-one functions $f$ from the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to the set $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ so that $f(x) \neq x$ and $f(x) \neq 2n - x + 1$ for all $x$?

I'm getting that the number of such functions is total number of one-to-one functions here (which is $(2n)!/n!$) - $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n|$ where $A_i$ is the set of one-to-one functions such that $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=2n-x+1$ for some $x$.

Where do I go from there?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll work this one out in detail to give you a model for similar problems.

As usual, $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) says that

$$\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|\;,$$

so the first step is to figure out what $\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|$ is for an arbitrary non-empty subset $I$ of $[n]$.

Clearly

$$|A_k|=\frac{2(2n-1)!}{n!}$$

for each $k\in[n]$: there are $2$ choices for $f(k)$ and $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}$ for the rest of $f$. More generally, suppose that $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]$. There are $2$ choices for $f(k)$ for each $k\in I$, so

$$\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|=\frac{2^{|I|}(2n-|I|)!}{n!}\;,$$

and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\frac{2^{|I|}(2n-|I|)!}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^k(2n-k)!}{n!}\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^{k+1}2^k(2n-k)!\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, the total number of functions with the desired properties is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!}-\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^{k+1}2^k(2n-k)!&=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}+\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^k2^k(2n-k)!\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^k2^k(2n-k)!\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Upvoted (+1) as being canonical.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me understand the principle and definitely helped me understand how to do other problems! Accepted and +1

Comment: @Brian  Can you explain further how you got 2(2n-1)!/n! for |Ak|? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @discsq12: For a function in $A_k$ there are $2$ possible values for $f(k)$: $k$ and $2n+1-k$. Once we choose that value, the rest of $f$ can be any one-to-one function from $[n]\setminus\{k\}$ to $[2n]\setminus\{f(k)\}$; in other words, it’s a one-to-one function from a set of $n-1$ things to a set of $2n-1$ things. There are $$\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}=\underbrace{(2n-1)(2n-2)\ldots(n+1)}_{n-1\text{ factors}}$$ such functions, so altogether $|A_k|=2\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I understand the (2n - 1)!/n! but I'm not sure why we are multiplying by 2 and then 2^i.

Comment: @discsq12: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: sorry, I just edited my comment:  I understand the (2n - 1)!/n! but I'm not sure why we are multiplying by 2.

Comment: @discsq12: Because there are $2$ possibilities for $f(k)$. There are $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}$ one-to-one functions with $f(k)=k$ and another $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}$ one-to-one functions with $f(k)=2n+1-k$. All $=2\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}$ of those functions are in $A_k$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an explanation in words can be helpful here.
The answer is

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q 2^q 
{2n-q\choose n-q} (n-q)!$$

We start by computing the number of functions having at least $q\ge 1$
special points with a forbidden  assignment.  That means we must first
choose the $q$ slots:

$${n\choose q}$$

There are two possibilities for each slot, giving

$$2^q$$

Once the  special points are  assigned there are $2n-q$  elements left
over from which  we must select $n-q$ to fill  out the function. These
$n-q$ elements can occur in any order, so we have

$${2n-q\choose n-q}\times (n-q)!$$

Now  we want  to  assign a  weight  $\alpha_q$ to  the  counts of  the
functions having at least $q$ special points so that a function having
at  least one  special  point has  total  weight equal  to minus  one,
corresponding  to  subtraction  from  the  total  of  the  ${2n\choose
n}\times n!$  functions.  Suppose it  has $p$ special points.   Such a
function contributes to all $q\le p.$ The cumulative weight is

$$\sum_{q=1}^p {p\choose q} \alpha_q.$$

Choosing $\alpha_q = (-1)^q$ we get

$$\sum_{q=1}^p {p\choose q} (-1)^q = -1.$$

With this choice of weight,  functions with at least one special point
are counted zero times in the sum

$${2n\choose n} \times n!
+  \sum_{q=1}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q 2^q 
{2n-q\choose n-q} (n-q)!$$

because they are counted once in  the first term.  We absorb this term
into the sum and obtain the formula given at the beginning.

For Maple enthusiasts I present the Maple code to compute the first
few  values of  this sequence  by  total enumeration  and compare  the
result to the closed form expression.

```
with(combinat);

Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local comb, perm, func, pos, res;

    res := 0;

    comb := firstcomb(2*n, n);

    while type(comb, `set`) do
        perm := firstperm(n);

        while type(perm, `list`) do
            func :=
            [seq(op(perm[ind], comb), ind = 1..n)];

            for pos to n do
                if func[pos] = pos or
                func[pos] = 2*n+1-pos then
                    break;
                fi;
            od;

            if pos = n+1 then
                res := res + 1;
            fi;

            perm := nextperm(perm);
        od;

        comb := nextcomb(comb, 2*n);
    od;

    res;
end;

S := n-> add(binomial(n,q)*(-1)^q*2^q*
             binomial(2*n-q,n-q)*(n-q)!, q=0..n);
```

**Remark.** To be precise about it what we are computing with the $\alpha_q$ is of course the Möbius function of the poset of the subsets of [n] ordered by set inclusion which is $(-1)^q$ where $q$ is the number of elements in the subset.